# Why is Shandong named Lu?

Tags: china, toponymy

[Shandong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shandong), a Chinese province, is sometimes known as **Qilu**, after the [Zhou dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhou_dynasty) states of [Qi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi_(state)) and [Lu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lu_(state)).

However, its name is further shortened as **Lu**. For example, [Shandong cuisine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shandong_cuisine) is known in Chinese as **Lu cuisine**. Why use Lu, and not Qi?

Out of its namesakes, Qi seems to be the more important one. It was a major state throughout the Zhou dynasty:

- [Duke Huan of Qi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duke_Huan_of_Qi) was one of the [Five Hegemons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Hegemons)
- it was one of the [Seven Warring States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Warring_States)
- it lasted longer than any other Zhou state, being the last to fall to [Qin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_(state))

Compared to Qi, Lu was always a minor state. The only advantages it has over Qi are:

- Its rulers descended from a cadet branch of the royal [House of Ji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C4%AB). Qi's rulers descended from the Zhou Prime Minister [Jiang Ziya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiang_Ziya), although both states were equal in [noble rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_nobility#Peer_ranks_of_the_Zhou_dynasty), that of Duke (公).
- It was the home of Confucius, and thus had outsized cultural significance

Wikipedia claims the last point was the reason for choosing Lu, although this statement is unsupported. Or was it for another reason? Is it more common in Chinese to abbreviate using the second character?